# Is there any comparable alternative to Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, size, dll

I love the idea of Qt, however I use it not only for open source but closed source development. This isn't a real problem because I just license under the LGPL and distribute the DLLs needed. I've run into a problem though unfortunately.

The compiled statically linked executable is 4.36 MB. Not too shabby.

The compiled dynamically linked executable is 250 KB, however I also must include almost 35 MB in DLL files with the installation. This is REALLY tacky and no matter how I look at it I cannot justify the size-use ratio. This, and I simply cannot afford a commercial license. Talk about price gouging start up developers.

Anyway, you see my problem. My program performs only one function. 35 MB is too large. Unfortunately I've heard horror stories about how poorly maintained WxWidgets is but given my situation I'm afraid I'll be forced to use it. Can anyone recommend me a alternative that is nearly as powerful but won't result in the bloat an LGPL compiled Qt executable brings? Thank you!

Comment: What do you use Qt for? Only GUI? Is it not possible to pack only needed parts of Qt with your application? You don't have to ship whole Qt if you don't use every part of it. Look for which DLLs your executable really depends on.

Comment: This is the problem. Those ARE the required dlls. QtCore4, QtGUI, etc. The compiled Hello World executable required 30 MB in dlls alone :/.

Comment: what is that *one function* your program is performing? Platform independent alternatives might be available for that functionality without involving Qt..

Comment: Even if I select all Qt DLLs in my Qt build (including Phonon and WebKit), I barely get up to 35MB. What is it your application is doing and are you absolutely sure you need all DLLs?

Comment: Could it be because I'm using the SDK vs. actually compiling it myself with the DLLs? I actually compiled the static executables with as many optimization commands as I possibly could.

Comment: You may recompile them using size optimizations. For example, on VS2008 qtWebkit, optimized by size, weights only 10.3 mb, and not optimized by size - 20.6 mb. if you disable inline functions, there also will be size reduction. Using new ASM command sets also reduces size...

Comment: 9 times out of 10 the problem is your packager.   It's probably packaging *all* of the QT dll's... even the web dev framework, which is huge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you wrap all the functionality you need in a separate statically compiled dll and link your program dynamically with that. You can release the source code of the statically compiled dll since it's just a wrapper. And overall you'll still comply with LGPL.

Comment: IANAL so of course you should confirm on your own whether this really is the case.

Comment: That effectively creates a new library consisting of a strict subset of Qt, something that's perfectly legal. You'd just need to ensure that you made available _both_ the source for _your_ library, _and_ the source for the Qt version it was built from. The LGPL's requirement is that the end user be able to replace the library with a modified version, which this would fulfill.

Comment: Very interesting loophole. So, if I understand this correctly, I'd handle all of the Qt work in a separate static library. This file falls under LGPL because it links to Qt directly, so I'd have to release that under the LGPL. The question is, because I link to the static library that handles all of the Qt work indirectly doesn't that mean I still link to Qt?

Comment: @Dr.McNinja: You _always_ "link" to Qt. What you avoid with hawk's method is incorporating Qt directly into your executable through _static_ linking, which is where the LGPL gets you in trouble. Hawk's proposal is just a quick and convenient way of stripping out the bits of Qt you don't use and building a new _dynamic_ library (DLL) with the rest. It's functionally identical to downloading the Qt source, stripping out the code you don't need, and building a DLL out of the result. As long as you release the source for that new, smaller DLL, you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fltk.org/
Have a look at that :) It's simpler, open source and might do enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can suggest is to try [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) (or similar) packing the dynamic DLL's to get their size down, depending on how much code vs data/resources the DLL's contain you can get pretty impressive results.

Comment: For example: QtCore+QtGui goes from 10 MB to 4.3 MB. Though I personally think the increased memory usage isn't worth the saved disk space.