# C++ Core Application Development framework , Open Source , Cross Platform

Tags: c++, frameworks, open-source

Like Qt  , do we have any core application development framework in c++.
I think the qt is mainly for GUI applications . I need something other than QT , which gives a much faster running code ...
Visual Studio for c++ is a good choice , but its not an open source and cross platform one ..

Comment: What makes you think Qt is slow? It is about what operations you want to do for your application that matters and not the framework you use.

Comment: @Rohit Simpler like QT , Cross platform , opensource , for non gui application developement ( core applications like servers )

Comment: @ksming , Yeah what your saying is true, i want to develop some core applications not gui things so first priority is for speed of execution of code ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6119816/1155650 does this help u?

Comment: @Rohit I dont want a GUI f/w ...

Comment: Selecting the right FW is harder than creating the SW

Comment: @megabyte1024 Boost Library is a good choice , but not so easy to use ..

Comment: @Akhil Thayyil. Sorry. I published the comment as an answer. Which part is "not easy to use"? The only issue which I mentioned, it's increased compilation time.

Comment: @megabyte1024 Boost is preferable choice , as most parts of boost is already been added to c++ std , but i found it bit difficult to understand boost than QT , as QT gives good examples and an good ide for development ..

Comment: Core development framework - what do you mean? Libraries for cross-platform development or IDE for develop applications?

Comment: @Akhil Thayyil BOOST has also a lot of examples. You wrote about Visual Studio and it is also a very good IDE to work with BOOST. I think BOOST perfectly passes for core operations not involving GUI.

Comment: You know you can develop code without a GUI and without using any of the QT classes while using something like qt creator? The generated code will not be slower than that generated by VC (usually gcc generates slightly faster code). Why isn't this a viable alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is not exacly clear what you mean by framework you might want to clarify that a bit more. Anyways, I am a happy user of [boost](http://www.boost.org/) as libraries for generic functionality and use [eclipse + cdt](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers-includes-incubating-components/indigosr2) as IDE to do coding and debugging. Boost, eclipse and the cdt are open source and cross-platform.

Answer (score 3):

To put it bluntly, to me it sounds like you're wasting your time and do not have clearly defined goal for your application. No framework can fix this problem. Write down application specification, list of target platform, check what functionality is required but missing, search for existing libraries, then use them.

> I think the qt is mainly for GUI applications

You're mistaken.
In Qt 4 GUI component is optional. You are free to design console applications using QCoreApplication instead of QApplication for application object. As a bonus you get access to some GUI-related classes (not all of them, though - many require QApplication).

> which gives a much faster running code

Making code run fast is your responsibility. If it runs slowly, then it is your fault until proven otherwise. Qt 4 is very fast, at least as far as GUI performance is concerned. Poor selection of algorithms, abuse of memory allocation routines and many other things can negatively impact performance. Switching to different framework won't fix those. Instead of searching for different tool, profile your code, search for bottlenecks and fix them.

> Visual Studio for c++ is a good choice

It is not cross-platform. It is also not a framework - only IDE+compiler.

> Cross Platform

Depending on your application you could even develop cross-platform application in standard C++ without any frameworks while using CMake/Scons/Autotools for build process. Unix-like environments have POSIX standard they more or less attempt to conform to, which can be used (on windows it requires cygwin/msys to be functional). Aside from that there's Boost. You could even ditch C++ and switch to scripted language to ensure portability. It all depends n your goals. Since you haven't said what you're writing it isn't possible to recommend anything specific aside from Boost. In addition to boost there are several frameworks (wxWidgets, Fox Toolkit, GTK) that may or may not meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Which features should have the framework? How about the [BOOST](http://www.boost.org/)? It's not a framework as QT and wxWidgets, but it has a lot of features like delegates aka signals, threads, inter-process communications, network, etc.